# Best way to create python web service and c# client application

Tags: c#, python, web-services

I am looking for a simple and reliable way to create Python Web Service and consume it from the .Net (c#) application.

I found plenty of different libraries, where one is better than another, but nobody seems to have a complete working example with Python Web Service and some simple c# client. And reasonable explanations of steps to configure and run

Comment: Best way is to learn by making mistakes if only few has traversed that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may start your practice by:

1. Install ZSI
2. Create a WSDL for your service

The full [example](http://www.pha.com.au/kb/index.php/Python_SOAP_Tutorial_-_Creating_a_WEB_Service_with_ZSI)

4.On client(C#) follow this [tutorial](http://documentation.softwareag.com/adabas/asg243/tutorials/acc_dnet.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting using [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/). It is very simple to use, non-blocking web-server written in Python. I've been using it in the past and I was shocked how easy it was to learn and use it.

I am strongly encouraging you to design your API with REST in mind. It will make your API simple, and easy to consume by any language/platform available.

Please, have a look at the 'Hello World' sample - it has been taken from Torando's main site:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

As for the client part - there is nothing complicated:

```
string CreateHTTGetRequest(string url, string cookie)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    return content;
}
```

In case the server is running on your local machine, the URI is: 'http://localhost:8888/'

Comment: Didn't know tornado, although I wrote an API myself. That one is running with apache+mod_wsgi though.